# How to modify the localization information of the original menu?

Tags: abp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrUnU.png)

How do I change this localized menu name? This is the menu for third-party modules。
I try to add localization comments, but it does not cover the third party's menu, presumably because the location of the localized resource is different.

zh-Hans.json

```
{
  "culture": "zh-Hans",
  "texts": {
    "Menu:Administration": "系统管理"
  }
}
```

I end up finding this menu, reassigning it, is there any way to omit this?

```
        var adminMenu = context.Menu.GetMenuItemOrNull(DefaultMenuNames.Application.Main.Administration);
        if(adminMenu != null)
        {
            adminMenu.DisplayName = l["Menu:Administration"];
        }
```

Comment: You could follow this ABP Blog Post to change localization of depending modules -> https://community.abp.io/posts/how-to-override-localization-strings-of-depending-modules-ba1oy03l